# How to SSR CSS modules?

Tags: webpack, next.js, server-side-rendering, css-modules

I'm using NextJS with CSS modules. There's a use case in which I need to render a bunch of components to a string HTML so that I can do some processing on it.

To do so, I need to extract the CSS used within the components and have it ready so that I can basically render it SSR. For instance with [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/), I can do the following:

```
export const generateHTML = (): string => {
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
  const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(<Page/>));
  const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags(); // THIS

  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        ${styleTags}  // THIS
      </head>
      <body>
        ${html}
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
}
```

How would I achieve this with CSS modules? How can I get a stylesheet (string) with all the used CSS so that I can SSR it?

Comment: You should take a look at [Loadable Components](https://loadable-components.com/docs/server-side-rendering/) SSR with splichunk is pretty easy.

Comment: Hey @RahulKumar, I tried making it work but with no luck. Can you post an answer with this + nextjs and I'll mark it as Accepted :pray:

Comment: Not sure how to configure splitchunks to work with loadable components in the next config

Comment: How are you loading the css for a component? Are those styled component?